# Summarize data in array of objects by common date

Tags: javascript

This is my data,
"time" is number

```
[
    {
        "time": 202007150800,
        "count": 10
    },
    {
        "time": 202007160700,
        "count": 11
    },
    {
        "time": 202007160900,
        "count": 12
    }
]
```

How do I use "time" group data from 8 o'clock yesterday to 8 o'clock today and sum "count"
,For example, 7/15 data is 7/15 08:00 - 7/16 07:00

like this:

```
[
    {
        "time": 20200715,
        "count": 21
    },
    {
        "time": 20200716,
        "count": 12
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the same by yourself? If yes, then please that code too.

Comment: Shouldn't the second element be grouped with the third?

Comment: The logic is ambiguous as presented here, `7/15` data should be `7/15 08:00 - 7/16 07:59`, so that `7/16` data can be `7/16 08:00 - 7/17 07:59` and so on.

Comment: Sorry, is 7/15 08:00 - 7/16 07:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
function mapData(data) {

    let result = [];

    data.forEach(element => {
        let t = element.time + 9200;

        let substr = t.toString().substr(0, 8);
        if(!result[substr])
            result[substr] = 0;
        result[substr] += element.count;
    });

    let returnResult = [];

    result.forEach((element, index) =>
        returnResult.push({
            time: index,
            count: element
        })
    );
    return returnResult;
}
```

Comment: @Benji : while above solution appears simple to comprehend, it's outright wrong as ***it does not provide the expected output for your original input, neither it passes [basic tests](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/KKVGEJJ?editors=0010)*** and may result in complete nonsense, like `time: 20200832` i.e. 32-nd of August

Comment: @Benji : Furthermore, above solution is [terribly slow](https://jsbench.me/d7kcqicimr/1)